# How to call React js from Layout.cshtml (Combine React Routing and ASP.NET MVC Routing)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, reactjs, routes

I have an application that is written in ASP.NET MVC core so the View is in cshtml.
The routing is the usual asp.net mvc routing. 
I have a new module that is written using React JS.
How do integrate the routing of react js and ASP.NET MVC since one located in js file and the other one is in server code?

Comment: I'd ask why you want to do this in the first place, given that a server-based MVC and React don't really go together. React is a JS application running in a browser window, while an MVC website pretty much constantly switches location.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply try hitting the API controller and take any response  like 200 and then simply redirect to the react js url.

Comment: Thank you for your answer kunal